# Implicit and Explicit Solution of IVP for $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2-1}{x^2-1}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I find the implicit and explicit solution of the IVP $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2-1}{x^2-1}$$  given that $y(2)=2$. And also I need to say what the interval of definition of the solution is.

What I got up to:

I got to the point: $$\frac{y+1}{y-1}=\frac{x+1}{x-1}+c$$ by doing integration by seperation. I don' know if this is an implicit or explicit solution and I don't know what the interval is. I think it should be all real numbers, but I am not sure. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a slight mistake in your calculations. Your implicit (general) solution should be of the form

$$\frac{y-1}{y + 1} = A\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)$$

where $A$ is a constant. Then the explicit solution is obtained by solving for $y$ in the above equation:

$$y = \frac{1 + A\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)}{1 - A\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)} = \frac{(1 + A)x + (1 - A)}{(1 - A)x + (1 + A)}$$

Use the initial condition $y(2) = 2$ to find $A$, thereby giving the implicit and explicit solutions of your IVP.

Comment: Can you tell me what the interval is.

Comment: I ended up getting y=x

Comment: Yes, $y = x$ is the correct solution of the IVP.

Comment: What is the interval?

Comment: @Bailee it's $(1,\infty)$. Since $dy/dx$ is discontinuous where $x^2 - 1 = 0$, i.e., at $x = 1$ and $x = -1$, the possible intervals of definition are $(-\infty, -1)$, $(-1,1)$, and $(1,\infty)$. Among these intervals, $(1,\infty)$ is the only one that contains the initial point $x_0 = 2$ of the IVP. So $(1,\infty)$ is indeed the interval of definition.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is $${{y-1}\over{y+1}}=C{{x-1}\over{x+1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

by inspection $y = x$ is a solution. by uniqueness, it is the solution.